# CMD.exe /C with parameters not working

Tags: cmd

Have executed the below query in Run but it is not working

`cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files\PackageForTheWeb 4\pftwwiz.exe" "C:\Software\PackageForTheWeb 4\Projects\setup_VQA7777.pfw" -a -s`

The below query is working when I open the command prompt and execute the query

`"C:\Program Files\PackageForTheWeb 4\pftwwiz.exe" "C:\Software\PackageForTheWeb 4\Projects\setup_VQA7777.pfw" -a -s`

I have to execute the file in my C# project.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to use cmd for this in C#.

In C# you can use:

```
Process.Start("C:\Program Files\PackageForTheWeb 4\pftwwiz.exe");
```

or

```
Process.Start("C:\Software\PackageForTheWeb 4\Projects\setup_VQA7777.pfw", "-a -s");
```

Here is the msdn description: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx

I hope this helps you.